# Assigning a value to multiple Id's in database schema

Tags: database, oracle, database-schema

```
Id  Value
```

A single value can be assigned to any number of Id's - one, two or many. Can also store the number of Id's to which the value is applied to. Would appreciate if anyone provides recommendations around the same as to how to represent that as part of database schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to normalize the idea of a VALUE then it should be it's own table..

like this:

```
VALUE
-------
value_id
actual_value
```

then you would link it to the other id

like

```
VALUE_ID_LINK
-------------
value_id
other_id
```